# Load numpy .npy files Opencv C++

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to load data saved from python as .npy files in Opencv C++.
I found about Filestorage XML/YML in Opencv, but is there a direct way to do that ?

Regards
SMW

Answer (score 3):

There is a C++ .npy reader at https://github.com/rogersce/cnpy

.npy is documented at  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/doc/neps/nep-0001-npy-format.rst should you want to know how write your own (doesn't look like a big job).

Comment: Thanks B... . I did write my own function which saves numpy array to xml/yml such it can be loaded in Opencv using FileStorage. I will try to look in to your suggestion and may be compare with my idea.

Answer (score 1):

I know i am late but you can use xtensor to load and save npy files

[docs](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/file_loading.html)

[github](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor)